# How to get repeatable sample using Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, sampling, presto

I am trying to get a sample of data from a large table and want to make sure this can be repeated later on. Other SQL allow repeatable sampling to be done with either setting a seed using set.seed(integer) or repeatable (integer) command. However, this is not working for me in Presto. Is such a command not available yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is that you can simulate the sampling by adding a column (or create a view) with random stuff (such as UUID) and then selecting rows by filtering on this column (for example, UUID ended with '1'). You can tune the condition to get the sample size you need.

By design, the result is random and also repeatable across multiple runs.

Comment: Can you consider adding some example presto SQL code for this?

Comment: This is _not_ reproducible across runs. `uuid()`, by design, will return a different UUID every time it's invoked. So if you update the data, then add UUIDs again and use those to sample, you will get a different sample. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71749724/3149788) if you want to reproducibly sample.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Presto 0.263 or higher you can use `key_sampling_percent` to *reproducibly* generate a double between 0.0 and 1.0 from a `varchar`.

For example, to reproducibly sample 20% of records in `table` using the `id` column:

```
select
    id
from table
where key_sampling_percent(id) < 0.2
```

If you are using an older version of Presto (e.g. AWS Athena), you can use what's in the [source code for `key_sampling_percent`](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/ae771008b3e1c9763ff78b4df539d5d319a041ba/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/sql/SimpleSamplingPercent.java#L31):

```
select
    id
from table
where (abs(from_ieee754_64(xxhash64(cast(id as varbinary)))) % 100) / 100. < 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you have to use `from_big_endian_64` instead of `from_ieee754_64` to get reliable results in Athena. Otherwise I got no many numbers close to zero because of the negative exponent.

```sql
select id
    from table
    where (abs(from_big_endian_64(xxhash64(cast(id as varbinary)))) % 100) / 100. < 0.2
```

Comment: What does this answer add more than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71749724/16019058)?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a simple intermediate table with selected ids:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <temp1>
AS
SELECT <id_column>
FROM <tablename> TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10);
```

This will contain only sampled ids and will be ready to use it downstream in your analysis by doing `JOIN` with data of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this will work, since I'm working with very large datasets, I would like to avoid joins.